# Show $s_{\delta, \lambda} \in \textrm{Sp}(\textrm{V}, \langle , \rangle)$ and $s_{\delta, \lambda} \circ s_{\delta, \mu} = s_{\delta, \lambda + \mu}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $K$-vectorspace with a skew-symmetric bilinear for $\langle , \rangle$. For an arbitrary vector $\delta \in V$ and an arbitrary scalar $\lambda \in K$ we define $$s_{\delta, \lambda}:V \to V, v \mapsto v + \lambda \langle \delta, v \rangle \delta$$

i) Show that $s_{\delta, \lambda} \in \textrm{Sp}(\textrm{V}, \langle , \rangle)$ (Sp = symplectic group).

ii) Show that for arbitrary $\lambda, \mu \in K$ and $\delta \in V$: $s_{\delta, \lambda} \circ s_{\delta, \mu} = s_{\delta, \lambda + \mu}$

So far I have:

i) Definition: $\textrm{Sp}(V, \langle , \rangle) =$ {$f \in \textrm{Gl}(V)| \forall v,w \in V: \langle f(v), f(w) \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle$}

$$\begin{align}
     \langle s_{\delta, \lambda}(v), s_{\delta, \lambda}(w) \rangle & = \langle v + \lambda\langle \delta, v \rangle \delta,  w + \lambda \langle \delta, w \rangle \rangle \\
     & = ...? \\
     & = ...? \\
     & = \langle v, w \rangle
     \end{align}$$

ii) $$\begin{align}
      s_{\delta, \lambda} \circ s_{\delta, \mu} & = s_{\delta, \mu}(s_{\delta, \lambda} (v)) \\
      & = s_{\delta, \lambda}(v) + \mu \langle \delta, s_{\delta, \lambda}(v) \rangle \delta \\
      & = v + \lambda \langle \delta, v \rangle \delta + \mu \langle \delta, v  + \lambda \langle \delta, v \rangle \delta \rangle \delta \\
      & = v + \lambda \langle \delta, v \rangle \delta + \mu \langle \delta, v \rangle  + \langle \delta, \lambda \langle \delta, v \rangle \delta \rangle \delta \\
      & = ...? \\
      & = v + (\lambda + \mu)\langle\delta, v \rangle \delta \\
      & = s_{\delta, \lambda + \mu}
    \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a *skew-symmetric bilinear form* all throughout. For example $$\begin{align}
  \langle v + \lambda \langle \delta ,v\rangle \delta ,w + \lambda \langle \delta ,w\rangle \delta \rangle  = \langle v,w + \lambda \langle \delta ,w\rangle \delta \rangle  + \langle \lambda \langle \delta ,v\rangle \delta ,w + \lambda \langle \delta ,w\rangle \delta \rangle  \cr 
   = \langle v,w\rangle  + \langle v,\lambda \langle \delta ,w\rangle \delta \rangle  + \langle \lambda \langle \delta ,v\rangle \delta ,w\rangle  + \langle \lambda \langle \delta ,v\rangle \delta ,\lambda \langle \delta ,w\rangle \delta \rangle  \cr 
   = \langle v,w\rangle  + \lambda \langle \delta ,w\rangle \langle v,\delta \rangle  + \lambda \langle \delta ,v\rangle \langle \delta ,w\rangle  + {\lambda ^2}\langle \delta ,v\rangle \langle \delta ,w\rangle \langle \delta ,\delta \rangle  \end{align} $$

Assuming the field is not of characteristic $0$, then the form is alternating, so $\langle \delta,\delta\rangle=0$, and $\lambda \langle \delta ,w\rangle \langle v,\delta \rangle  + \lambda \langle \delta ,v\rangle \langle \delta ,w\rangle=\lambda \langle \delta ,w\rangle( \langle v,\delta \rangle  + \langle \delta ,v\rangle)=0$

Comment: Thank you, any idea about the ii) ?

Comment: @sj134 Should be exactly the same!